# 3 x 3 contingency table in R

Tags: r

**Example**

```
data <- data.frame("VPN" = c(1,2,3,4), "dV.bl" = c(0,0,1,2), "dV.post" = c(2,2,1,2))
```

Converting data to long form:

```
data.long <- data.frame("VPN" = rep(data$VPN, times=2), "dV" = c(data$dV.bl, data$dV.post),  "TP"=rep(c(0,1), each=4))
data.long <- data.long[order(data.long$VPN), ]
```

**My question is**: How do I get a 3x3 contingency table from this data in oder to be able to use it in the Stuart-Maxwell statistic?

The 3x3 table should look as such:

```
          TP2
          0  1  2
  ________________
  TP1  0 |0  0  2
       1 |0  1  0
       2 |0  0  1
```

However, If I'm using table(data.long$dV,data.long$TP), R returns a 2 x 3 table:

```
table(data.long$dV,data.long$TP)

  TP1  TP2
0  2   0
1  1   1
2  1   3
```

How do I get a 3x3 table? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! Adding `useNA="always"` just seems to add an additional row for NAs to a 2x3 contingency table

Comment: This still seems to just add an additional row of 0s to the 2x3 contingency table

Comment: Could you explain what `TP1` and `TP2` are ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The study used a repeated measures design with a categorical outcome variable that was measured twice in time.  TP1 means time point 1 (baseline) and TP2 is time point 2 (post intervention). TP1 =0, TP2 =1

Comment: OK. I suppose that in `dV.bl` there are the values of the categorical outcome at the baseline (T0) and in `dV.post` the values at T1. Right ? Is `VPN` only a counter ?

Comment: exactly! dV.bl is the categorical outcome at T0 and dV.post is the outcome at T1. And yes, VPN is a counter of participants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for your problem is:

```
data <- data.frame("VPN" = c(1,2,3,4), 
                   "dV.bl" = c(0,0,1,2), 
                   "dV.post" = c(2,2,1,2))

table(factor(data$dV.bl, levels=0:2), factor(data$dV.post, levels=0:2))

#    0 1 2
#  0 0 0 2
#  1 0 1 0
#  2 0 0 1
```